# Website Found waiting for reply

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I am Making a website in ASP.Net on C#. I use 4 queries to get the data from MS SQL Server database. Now the problem is sometime I get the page in browser quickly and sometimes only the "website found waiting for reply" in status bar of IE gettinh nothing..
Please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: Does this happen only when you have recently made changes?

Comment: Are any parameters used by these queries? If so, what types of parameters and do the values of the parameters vary?

Answer (score 1):

User **Response.flush** to forcefully flush the server response.

Use **[FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/)** for client-side debugging.

[image]
<sub>(source: [getfirebug.com](http://getfirebug.com/net.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

No this does not happen only when I made any change to code.
Recently I used stored procedure to get the resultset from MS SQl Server database, I add one parameter of type varchar with that the result will be filtered.